# how do I use a different index controller in Zend other than indexcontroller

Tags: php, zend-framework, controller

if you use zend framework and just go to http://localhost, the site will call the index action of index controller.....is there a way to configure zend such that it will call some other controller when you access the index site?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either set the desired values through the FrontController's API

- [setDefaultControllerName](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Controller/Zend_Controller_Front.html#setDefaultControllerName): *base name of the default controller (normally "index")*
- [setDefaultAction](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Controller/Zend_Controller_Front.html#setDefaultAction): *base name of the default action (normally "index")*
- [setDefaultModule](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Controller/Zend_Controller_Front.html#setDefaultModule): *base name of the default module (normally "default")*

or, when using [`Zend_Application_Resource_FrontController`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.frontcontroller), you can set the desired values in your *application.ini* and they get applied automatically during bootstrap.

```
resources.frontController.defaultControllerName = "site"
resources.frontController.defaultAction = "home"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "static"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Zend_Controller_Front:

```
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $front->setDefaultControllerName('myDefaultController');
```